# Is my procedure correct for simulated flight approach using this IAP after complete STAR?

Tags: flight-simulator, iaps, sid-star

I usually "fly" with flightsimulator (FlightGear, because is O.S. and freeware).
I try to make the fly real as possible, and I try to use IAP, is this procedure correct to
approach RWY 28 of LSZH Zurich Airport?

[image]

I'm on FIX AMIKI, I can use this IAP after complete STAR

AMIKI then KLO then 84° and at D16(16 miles distance from KLO) i take 275° and allign to ILS?

Or I make all/something wrong?
How did you proceed to enter in RWY 28 ils?
Thanks

Comment: I fixed the question with correct terms, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the procedure envisions a teardrop entry into the holding pattern at KLO to reverse your course and get back to KLO in a position that you can commence the procedure track to the east.

So, the steps would be:

- AMIKI
- ZUE
- KLO
- outbound on a 234 track for 1 minute (the teardrop entry)
- Right turn & inbound to KLO on the 084 inbound course
- Outbound to the KLO 084/16
- Right turn & intercept the ILS

Comment: And this is why ATC is your friend with Vectors.  (two course reversals?!)

Comment: @MichaelHall I didn't claim I thought it'd be fun!  Yes, definitely, vectors to final, thank you.

Comment: I agree with @Bianfable's answer, which explains the other options & why these steps would be required. My answer elaborates on his 3rd point. His early observation that radar vectors is what you'd expect in reality, is spot-on.

Comment: Thanks, why one minute? I cannot find in my chart

Comment: @elbarna The one minute is just the standard way of flying the teardrop entry into a holding pattern. You won't find it on the chart. Technically, you could fly any entry into the hold as long as you stay in the protected area, but a teardrop entry with a one minute leg is the recommended procedure in this case.

Comment: Thanks, now is clear

Answer (score 10):

First of all, what you show is not a STAR. There are several STARs at LSZH that **end** at AMIKI (NEGRA 2A, RILAX 2A, TRA 2A). What happens after AMIKI is the **approach transition**.

There are 3 ways to get from AMIKI to the ILS for runway 28:

- **Radar Vectors:** ATC will give you vectors onto final approach. This would most likely happen in reality
- **RNAV Transition:** There is an RNAV transition from AMIKI to RAMEM called AMIKI28 transition:

  > AMIKI - ZH382 - ZH450 - ZH452 - ZH454 - ZH456 - ZH458 - ZH460 - ZH464 - RAMEM

  If your aircraft is RNAV 1 capable (GNSS or DME/DME required), this would be the preferred transition to fly. From RAMEM (the D10.3 point on your chart), you can start the ILS approach.
- **Radio-based Transition:** This is what you show on your ILS chart. You would only fly this if you don't get radar vectors and are not RNAV 1 certified.

Regarding your description of the procedure: you have a problem when arriving from ZUE at KLO. You cannot directly turn outbound to 084° because the change in course is too much. ICAO PANS-OPS only allows up to 30° turns when aligning for the reversal procedure:

> Unless the procedure specifies particular entry restrictions, reversal procedures shall be entered from a track within ±30° of the outbound track of the reversal procedure. However, for base turns, where the ±30° direct entry sector does not include the reciprocal of the inbound track, the entry sector is expanded to include it.

<sup>(ICAO Document 8168, Vol 1 §4, 3.3.3.1)</sup>

Therefore, what you'd have to do is enter the hold at KLO and use the hold to align yourself with the outbound track of 084°. Then you continue the procedure as described.